# Resolve ambiguous template

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguous

I would like to know if it is possible to resolve this ambiguous template functions:

```
//function1
template<typename returnType>
returnType call()
{
    //function with return type
}

//function2
template<typename var>
void call()
{
    //function without return type  
}

call<int>();  //call function1
call<void>(); //call function2
```

I would like to prevent the following solution:

```
    //function1
template<typename returnType>
returnType call()
{
    //function with return type
}

//function2
void call()
{
    //function without      
}

call<int>();  //call function1
call(); //call function2
```

Comment: Use specialization rather than overloading

Comment: Why not having two functions at all? You can't use them polymorphically and they're likely semantically different altogether

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly specialise the template for `void`:

```
//function2
template<>
void call<void>()
{
    //function without return type  
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with the return type, that's overloading

Comment: @DavidKernin: I don't know what you mean. You can do that, and it's template specialisation, not overloading. Demo: http://ideone.com/6N53rW

Comment: Thats a nice solution, but is it possible to have 2 template arguments  and only specialise one type? like this http://ideone.com/7IYfPp

Comment: oh I thought of the same thing but I didn't know that template specializations were allowed to change the signature of the function. I learned something today..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get the point but I give it a try with SFINAE:

```
//function1
template<typename returnType>
typename std::enable_if
<
    !std::is_same< returnType, void >::value,
    returnType
>::type call()
{
    //function with return type
}

//function2
template<typename var>
typename std::enable_if
<
    std::is_same< var, void >::value
>::type call()
{
    //function without return type  
}
```

Comment: I shall admit Mike Seymour's answer is closer and simpler to your needs.